# PC with blackscreen does not power off

Tags: windows, power

I bought a new desktop PC and was doing Windows updates, when my PC just froze. After about an hour the screen went black.

The RGB Logo on the Case and GPU stay lit, but the RGB light on the RAM and watercooling block do not. Does this tell something? Has my PC maybe tried to go to sleep while it was frozen and that's why the lights went off?

I cannot even power off the PC with the power button on the case, when I hold it for >10 sec.

Would it be safe, to just unplug the power cord and then reconnect it? I just cannot think of what else I can do at this point.

Comment: It's new. Warranty. Send it back

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to unplug the computer for hardware, but not for the operating system. It does not mean, however, that it will fail because of it. Go ahead and unplug it. If your problem persists, you probably have a hardware problem, and you should return the PC if you have a warranty on it.

Nothing worse can happen then it is now if you unplug the computer.